# Tools to measure TCP connection latency

Tags: linux, performance, tcp, latency

I want to measure the time it takes to finish TCP three-way handshake. I want to measure this on my Linux server. What are best practices for this? Notice that I want to measure this latency on server side and for all connections that are being accepted.

Comment: Is it the time between the server sent `SYN+ACK` and the client responded with `ACK`?

Comment: The time between the first SYN from client and  time when server sends SYN+ACK.

Comment: When measuring on the server the time when the client sent `SYN` is unavailable. The available time is when client's `SYN` has arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you're right I misunderstood the question.

I think you could achieve this using 'tcpdump' which is a really complete tool to see all the events in tcp traffic.

By your comment I see you want to measure the time between SYNC to the ACK packet.

With tcpdump you can filter the connections and specific packages:

```
tcpdump -r <interface> "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) != 0"
```

And by default the time will be displayed in the first column of tcpdump results.

Check [this](http://ask.xmodulo.com/capture-tcp-syn-ack-fin-packets-tcpdump.html), I think it could help.

I don't know if it's the best practice. Also If you want to manipulate that data, you can pipe the results and use awk or something similar.

EDIT: By searching in google I also found [this resource](https://www.circonus.com/2013/07/understanding-service-latencies-via-tcp-analysis/) which is really interesting.

Comment: Your method can only be used in client side and can not measure latency of all incoming requests to a server. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Having connected, `telnet` command then waits for user input.